# Representability of the sheaf $\mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathrm{SL}_2)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, representable-functors

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spm{Spm}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\Hom{Hom}$Let $T$ be the topos of $\Spm\mathbb{Q}_p$-rigid analytic spaces, $G$ an abstract group, and $\Hom(G,\SL_2)$ the sheaf which associates to an affinoid $X\in T$ with Tate algebra $A$ the set of *continuous* homomorphisms from $G$ to $\SL_2(A)$.

When $G$ is a finite group, generated by $r$ elements, the sheaf $\Hom(G,\SL_2)$ may be represented as a scheme by identifying it as being cut out from $\SL_2^r$ subject to the conditions coming from the relations of $G$.

Is there any obstruction to the representability of the same Hom sheaf when $G$ is infinite? I am particularly interested in the case when $G$ is profinite, and more precisely the absolute Galois group of the rationals.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the profinite case, do you really want homomorphisms $G \to \operatorname{SL}_2(A)$ instead of *continuous* homomorphisms?

Comment: Yeah, I want a continuous morphism. I will edit my question indeed. Otherwise the same construction works.

Comment: If the Hom sheaf is representable for every finite group $G$, then for every profinite group, the sheaf of continuous homomorphisms is representable by the associated ind scheme.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Perhaps it would be easier to specialize to the case where $G = \mathbb{Z}_p$ under addition.

Comment: I missed that you are specifically looking at continuous maps to $\textbf{SL}_2(A)$.  I thought that you were talking about the sheaf of groups of $\textbf{SL}_2$ on the category of schemes, with no extra topological / analytic structure.  Then "continuous" means "factors through a finite quotient".  So the functor is representable by the ind scheme associated to all finite quotients.  I do not know the answer for $\textbf{SL}_2(A)$ with its natural topological structure.